# INNER JOIN table and return all joined results as CSV (not separate records)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables with the following data.  I would like to return all data when the two tables are joined.  For instance, `SELECT t1.data, t2.data FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.t1_id=t2.id WHERE t1.id=1;`  Now the tricky part.  I don't want to return 3 rows but only one, and I would like t2.data to be CSVs.  For instance, the above query would return `"bla1","hi1,hi2,hi2"` (if no join results, then null or "", and not ",").  Is this fairly easy with just SQL, or am I better off using PHP, etc?  If so with just SQL, how?  Thanks

```
t1
-id
-data

t2
-id
-t1_id
-data

t1
-id=1, data="bla1"
-id=2, data="bla2"
-id=3, data="bla3"

t2
-id=1, t1_id=1, data=hi1
-id=2, t1_id=1, data=hi2
-id=3, t1_id=1, data=hi3
-id=4, t1_id=2, data=hi4
```

Comment: @FathahRehmanP.  Are you sure?  I seem to think it will return `bla1,hi1|bla1,hi2|bla1,hi3`.

Comment: in your query you used t2.t1_id=t2.id actually it is t2.t1_id=t1.id

Comment: @FathahRehmanP  Oops!  my bad.  You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) which concatenates non-null values from a group using a delimiter (comma by default)

```
SELECT t1.data, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.data)
FROM t1 JOIN t2 
 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
WHERE t1.id = 1;
```

Example on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68154/5

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CONCAT` or `CONCAT_WS` to "stick" column values together and `GROUP_CONCAT` to "stick" row values together.

Example:

```
SELECT
        x, y, z
    FROM
        table;
```

Turns into:

```
SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('"', x, '","', y, '","', z, '"') SEPARATOR '\n')
    FROM
        table
    GROUP BY x; -- considering x would be the unique row identifier
```

The above example will return exactly one cell (one row with one column).

Comment: I know CONCAT very well, but have never used GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: I just looked the function up, and it looks like exactly what I want.  +1

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT concat(t1.data,',',group_concat(t2.data)) FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON
 t2.t1_id=t1.id WHERE t1.id=1
    group by t1.data
```